# Calling Rust functions from inline assembly and calling conventions

Tags: c, rust, calling-convention

I'm working on some code that has be assembly within my Rust project. A coworker and I are discussing the calling conventions and I have been having trouble finding definitive resources for this.

As I understand it, the Rust calling conventions is undefined. So, when calling into assembly I should use the C calling convention to have something known.

I'm working between three functions:

`unsafe extern "C" fn f(a) -> b` is a naked function that is called only from Rust. It is entirely assembly and assumes parameters and return values are done as in C (On the stack and put in %eax).
Because this is marked as C and called from Rust, the compiler will ensure that wherever it is called, the C calling convention will be used on it.

`unsafe extern "C" fn g()` is also a naked function. It is never called from Rust. Only sometimes `f` returns to this function (that is the `ret` of `f` will pop the address of `g`).
While this is not a true C function (I know it is called from `f` and immediately use registers than `f` left values in), it will always call back into a rust function. Essentially, all this does is push parameters onto the stack and then `call` to `h` (by use of `sym h`).

`unsafe fn h` is then the last function here. It is only ever called from `g` via that `sym` in the inline assembly.
So, `h` should expect to be called with C conventions but can return with Rust conventions (in fact `h` never returns).

My question is then:

Does using `call` and `sym h` from my C function, g, alert the Rust compiler to consistently use C calling conventions in `h`?

I have previously marked `h` as `extern "C"` despite it being pure rust code. This, in my mind, would ensure the compiler respects that `h`'s arguments are C style. But, the code seems to work both ways. I don't want this to change if in the future Rust decides to optimize the call into `h` differently (and incorrectly).

Comment: If you don't have a reason to avoid `extern "C"` then I'd recommend it. I can't say for sure, but my understanding is that Rust will generally put values in registers where possible following the same convention as C - but that could very well change.

Comment: For `h`, I do get warnings when I use `extern "C"`. One thing I pass to `h` is a Rust function pointer and then I call it within `h`. This generates a warning about FFI's if `h` is marked C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `call` in inline assembly does not guarantee the function will use the C calling convention (in fact, the compiler has no insight into inline assembly at all). You do need to use `extern "C"`. Using Rust calling convention can *appear* to work (sometimes the calling conventions are equivalent) but it's not guaranteed.

If you pass a function pointers to `h()`, they also need to be `extern "C"` even if they are not called from assembly. As far as I can tell, there is no guarantee about the ABI of Rust-calling-convention functions, so you cannot even pass them, which is why the compiler warns you.

If `h()` does not return, you can mark it as having the return type `!`, which will make the compiler verify it indeed does not return (and if called from Rust, will also allow it to exploit this information).